# Angular: ngOnChanges not updating value

Tags: angular

I am new to ngOnchanges and facing below issue.

my parent component is setting recom value on ngOnChanges and sends the same value to child component. child receives the same as input in ngOnChanges. depending on some condition like totalVal>0 i set inputField  to true which is initially set to false. if inputField is true i show some component in reactive forms. but when my below structure execute model2Form() it still gets inputField as false. I cant post actual code so just created a structure as per my project as shown below.

Please suggest how do i solve this issue.

```
// parent component

ngOnchanges(){
  this.recom = [{
    totalVal: 5000,
    monthlydata: true
  }]
}

//child component

@Input()
private recom: any;

inputField: boolean = false;


ngOnChanges(){
  this.setValue();
  this.loadFuture();
}

setValue(){
  if(this.recom.totalVal > 0){
    this.inputField = true;
  }
}

loadFuture(){

}

model2Form(){

//getting input field as false even if i set it as true in setValue()

  if(inputField){
    this.heroForm.setControl('secretLairs', addressFormArray);
  }

}

<!-- parent component>

<parent-comp [recom]="recom"></parent-comp>


<!-- child component -->

<div [FormControlName]="secretLairs"> </div>
```

Comment: can you please provide your code at jsfiddle

Comment: Sorry Bro, I work in VDI so cant copy/paste code here so created a replica here

Comment: your parent ngChange is working but child one is not working ...right ??

Comment: let me know setValue(){ is getting called when changes done ???

Comment: provided answer , please have look to it

Comment: let me know if you ned more help to understnad it ..

Comment: child ngOnchanges only take input from parent. it is structure created by previous developer and i need to make change on it.

Comment: yes but ngOnchanges on parent will not get called untill you make any changes to @input property of it, i suggest you make use of some event like in my code i made use of textbox change event

Comment: i hope you got my point ...if you try my code it will give you clear view ..you have to make use of other way

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that you are trying to monitor changes on an Array. Arrays and Objects don't work so well with `ngOnChanges` because they are passed by reference, not value. Strings and Integers work well here because its easy for Angular to tell when the value has been changed. Since Javascript passes Objects and Arrays by reference, Angular will only trigger change detection when the reference changes.

Three ways to solve this really:

1. Store your complex value in a service as either a subject or BehaviorSubject if you have access to your values right away. Then subscribe to it throughout your application where needed. Every time a new value is pushed to the Observable, your components will run their logic on it.
2. Separate the properties you need to monitor into separate `@Inputs()` that are monitoring the value of something like a string or number.
3. The third way to solve this is to assign the Object/Array to an entirely new entity using [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) function and replacing the value of your property outright with the new entity thus creating a new reference.

Comment: La opción A funciona para mi

Answer (score 0):

change event ngOnchange only occur when there is any change done to your input property of component. So in your case `parentcomponent` has no input property and so ngOnchange does not fire for you.

I created code for you which is working - in below code i used parentcomponent in my `appcomponent.ts` and when I loaded, `ngOnchange` does not work, but child `ngOnchange` works and its input property gets changed.

So I changed child property in `OnChange` event of textbox control and when i changed value in my textbox control, then child control `ngOnchange` got triggered and updated value came.

If you pass input value to parent control and make change in that than you parent and child `ngOnchange`  will work.

Parent component

---

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnChanges, SimpleChanges, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'parentcomp',
    template: `
    this needs to be wok 
  <h3>Countdown to Liftoff (via local variable)</h3>
  <input type="text" [ngModel] = "display"  (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"/>
  {{display}}
  <Childcomp [recom] = "recom"> </Childcomp>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.recom = [{
            totalVal: 5000,
            monthlydata: false
        }];
    }
    display: string;
    recom: any;

    constructor() {
        this.display = "test";
    }

    onChange()
    {
        this.recom = [{
            totalVal: 5000,
            monthlydata: true
        }];

    }

    //this will not trigger 
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        debugger;
        this.recom = [{
            totalVal: 5000,
            monthlydata: true
        }];
    }
}
```

Child Component

---

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnChanges, SimpleChanges, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'Childcomp',
    template: `
  <h3>Child component</h3>

  `
})
export class Childcomponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input()
    private recom: any;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
       debugger;
       for (let propName in changes) {
        let chng = changes[propName];
        let cur:any  = chng.currentValue;
        let prev:any = chng.previousValue;
        alert(`${propName}: currentValue = ${cur[0].monthlydata}, previousValue = ${prev[0].monthlydata}`);
      }
    }
}
```