# Update view on ngOnChanges from @Input in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, javascript-objects, angular-components, ngonchanges

I have a @Input property in my child component of type Person and I'm passing the object from the parent component through an attribute

Full working code is available in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-ng-onchange)

I explored the following question I got the point that what they told in the answer but I tried the Object.assign and other things based on the answer but it fails to load the data in View.

- [Angular: ngOnChanges not updating value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47696848/angular-ngonchanges-not-updating-value)

How can I pass the Object through @Input and how can I do some manipulation once the object reached to the child component and need to update in the view?

Sample Code:

**App Component**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Person } from './models/person'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  person: Person = {
    firstName: 'Emma',
    lastName: 'Watson'
  };
}
```

**App Component HTML**:

```
<user [user-profile]="person"></user>
```

**User Component**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Person } from '../models/person';

@Component({
  selector: 'user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input('user-profile') profile: Person;

  person: Person;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.person = {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: ''
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges): void { 
    if(typeof this.profile !== 'undefined' 
      && typeof this.profile.firstName !== 'undefined' 
      && typeof this.profile.lastName !== 'undefined') {
        this.person.firstName = this.profile.firstName;
        this.person.lastName = this.profile.lastName;
    }
  }

}
```

**User Component HTML**:

```
Full Name: {{person.firstName}} {{person.lastName}}
```

I need to do some manipulation once I received the object from `@Input` and need to update it in the UI. I know the object is passing as reference but here I tried with `Object.assign` and I assigned the property with `undefined` and then the appropriate object nothing is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the asignment of `person` from `ngOnInit()`, ngOnInit runs after `ngOnChanges` so you are restting the values back to empty

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input('user-profile') profile: Person;

  person: Person = { firstName: '', lastName: '' };  // initialize it here

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() { 
    // this.person = {
    //   firstName: '',
    //   lastName: ''
    // }
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges): void { 



    if(typeof this.profile !== 'undefined' 
      && typeof this.profile.firstName !== 'undefined' 
      && typeof this.profile.lastName !== 'undefined') {
        console.log(this.profile)
        this.person.firstName = this.profile.firstName;
        this.person.lastName = this.profile.lastName;
        console.log(this.person)
    }
  }

}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-ng-onchange-qiyghn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser%2Fuser.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

It's because `ngOnInit` is ran after `ngOnChanges`. So you first set it, but then immediately reset it inside your `ngOnInit`.

See [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-ng-onchange-xkb1g6?file=src/app/user/user.component.ts) a working example.

Basically change your component person attribute to this:

```
person: Person = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: ''
};
```

and remove the `ngOnInit`.

You can also use a setter on the profile input, this way you don't need `ngOnChanges`:

```
@Input('user-profile') set profile(person: Person) {
  this.person.firstName = profile && profile.firstName || '';
  this.person.lastName = profile && profile.lastName || '';
}

person: Person = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: ''
};
```

Comment: Shall I do the initial assignment in the constructor ?

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan personally I think it's neater to do it on the property itself, but it doesn't really matter, the functionality will be the same. In Angular it's common to keep the constructor as empty as possible, and just use it for dependency injection

Comment: Don't mistake me. I marked based of FIFO. I up-voted very first for you answer.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan No worries :) I understand your reasoning. I actually did answer first, but edited within the minute, which made the edit merge with original answer, and updated the timestamp to after the other answer. But xyz deserves it more, he needs to points!