# Angular binding object from parent to child component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a problem with Anglular 8 and binding input parameters from parent component to child component.
I have the following setup:

-app.component.ts

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'parent-child-binding';
  showTitle: boolean = true;
  childData = [];

  onBoolean(){
    this.showTitle = !this.showTitle;
  }

  onComplexAdd(){
    this.childData.push("data 4");
    this.childData.push("data 5");
  }

  onComplexEdit(){
    this.childData[0] = "data 1 edited";
    this.childData[1] = "data 2 edited";
  }
  onComplexNew(){
    this.childData = [
      "data 1",
      "data 2",
      "data 3"
    ]
  }
}
```

-app.component.html

```html
<button (click)="onBoolean()">Boolean Bind</button>
<button (click)="onComplexNew()">Complex Object New</button>
<button (click)="onComplexEdit">Complex Object Edit</button>
<button (click)="onComplexAdd">Complex Object Add</button>
<app-child [data] = "childData" [showTitle]="showTitle"></app-child>
```

-child.component.ts

```ts
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  
  @Input() showTitle : boolean = true;
  @Input() data : Array<any>;
  
  constructor() { }


  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(changes);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

-child.component.html

```html
<h3 *ngIf="showTitle">Hello from child</h3>
<p *ngFor="let item of data">{{item}}</p>
```

So when I start I see the following:

[image: screen1]

and the console:

[image: console1]

When I click on the first button, as expected the title `Hello from child` shows and disappears.
When I click on the second button, as expected I see:

[image: screen2]

and the console:

[image: console2]

When I click on the third and forth buttons, nothing happens, not in the UI or console (the `onChanges` method seems that is not firing).

An I doing something wrong, or this that I want to achieve is not possible?

Best regards,
Julian

**EDIT**: After a comment and an answer from @MBB and @Apoorva Chikara, I've edited the code.

```html
<button (click)="onBoolean()">Boolean Bind</button>
<button (click)="onComplexNew()">Complex Object New</button>
<button (click)="onComplexEdit()">Complex Object Edit</button>
<button (click)="onComplexAdd()">Complex Object Add</button>
<app-child [data] = "childData" [showTitle]="showTitle"></app-child>
```

The edition made the buttons to act (do something), but it is not what I expect.
What I mean:
When I click on the `Complex Object Edit` button in the UI I see:

[image: screen3]

But in the console, there is no `ngOnChanges` callback firing, but the binded object has changed, as we can see on the print screen (`<p *ngFor="let item of data">{{item}}</p>`) fired and printed out the new values.

The same happens when I click on the `Complex Object Add` button. In the UI I see:

[image: screen4]

But in the console the `ngOnChanges` callback is not firing, but the UI is containing the new added data.

I'm confused, can anyone advice please?

Comment: Why cant you change the lines  (onComplexEdit) -> onComplexEdit() 
(onComplexAdd) -> onComplexAdd()

Comment: Hi @MBB thanks for your comment! I've edited the original question, because the change that you are suggesting is valid and proper, but not solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very simple fix, you are not calling a function instead assigning its definition :

```
<button (click)="onComplexEdit()">Complex Object Edit</button> // call it as a function
<button (click)="onComplexAdd()">Complex Object Add</button>// call it as a function
```

The issue, you are facing for `NgonChanges` is due to the arrays passed by reference, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47696848/angular-ngonchanges-not-updating-value) has a good explanation why this happens.

Comment: Hi @Apoorva Chikara thanks for your answer! I've edited the original question, because the change that you are suggesting is valid and proper, but not solve my problem.

Comment: What does it show in the Ngchanges? Can you add the details in the question now?

Comment: This is the problem. In the callback `ngOnChanges` I have a `console.log(changes)`, but in the last two buttons, there is nothing in the console window.

Comment: It seems you are getting value of type: `SimpleChanges` what is it? Try removing that and see what you get.

Comment: No, I'm not getting any value, because it seems that the callback function `ngOnChanges` never fires. If it fires there will be something in the `changes` argument, and it will be logged in the console window

Comment: If you see the updated values on the view that means the correct values are being passed. However, the values can't be seen in the console as they are passed by reference. To get into more details you should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47696848/angular-ngonchanges-not-updating-value).

Comment: Yes thanks! The second answer, answered my question. So it is not possible to achieve this behavior with the setup I have.

Comment: I'll mark this answer, but please, can you edit the answer, so the link to the other question is visible there. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, you can accept the answer. Meanwhile I will update the answer.